# VB.Net: Getting File Path from Data Files In Project

Tags: excel, vb.net, filepath

I'm creating a prototype that I will be putting on a CD and handing off to someone in Visual Studio. In this prototype, I have multiple Excel spreadsheets that I use for data.

I have the following line of code:

```
dataWorkBook = dataWorkbookApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Task\Prototype Data.xlsx")
```

Which opens one of the Excel Spreadsheets. This obviously wont work when I put it on a CD. I have created a Folder in my Visual Studio Project ("Data") and put all data files I have in it.

My questions is how do I get the file path to those files and put it in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added a folder named "Data" to your project and put all your data files in there, then set their `Build Action` property `Content` and their `Copy Local` property to `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer`, that "Data" folder will be in the program folder along with the EXE.  In that case, assuming a Windows Forms application, you can use `Application.StartupPath` to get the root folder path:

```
dataWorkBook = dataWorkbookApp.Workbooks.Open(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Data\Prototype Data.xlsx"))
```

That will work while debugging or in the final release, because it's always relative to the program folder.

Comment: I changed the code too : `dataWorkBook = dataWorkbookApp.Workbooks.Open(IO.Path.Combine(dataWorkbookApp.StartupPath, "Data Files\Prototype Data.xlsx"))` and received the error : `Sorry we couldnt find C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\Data Files\Prototype Data.xlsx`. I did not change the `Build Action` or `Copy Local` though. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. Could you explain a little deeper?

Comment: Is you project creating a Windows Forms application EXE or some other sort of output, like an Excel plugin?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer this, it shows multiple GUI's in Windows Forms, but the output (based on selections in those GUIs) is an Excel Spreadsheet

Comment: I also found something like this `Dim dataWorkbookPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath).FullName, "Data Files/Prototype Data.xlsx")` which I think would work, the only problem is i'm getting an error on `Application` saying `ExecutablePath is not a member of 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Application`